# How to change the NSScreen a NSWindow appears on

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have an application that will load a couple of windows depending on which button is pressed. All except one of these open on the mainScreen (the screen in which the main window is open in). One of them (the preference window) opens on the first screen (the screen with the menu bar). I cannot understand way it is doing this, is there a way to change the screen that a NSWindow opens on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not get toohtik's answer to work. What I ended up doing was subclassing NSWindow and then overriding constrainFrameRect: toScreen:. This will automatically open the new window on the "main screen" of the application.

```
- (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [super constrainFrameRect:frameRect toScreen:delegate.window.screen];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know why you have that behaviour but you can change it through initWithFrame method that takes NSScreen argument.