# Show window on multiple displays on os x

Tags: swift, macos

**Basic idea:**
The window will be show for *x* seconds every *n* minutes on all displays. To *"force"* the user to take a break.

My problem is to get the window to show on all displays, how can this be done with swift?

Comment: Instead of trying to have one window show on every display, you should consider having one window per display.

Comment: hmm so one instance per display, also an option do you have a guid for designation/assigning a window to a display ?

Comment: NSWindow has an initializer that accepts a `NSScreen` argument. After the fact, you can also [do shenanigans to move the window to another screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658582/how-to-move-nswindow-to-a-particular-screen).

Comment: thanks @zneak will try and get it to work based on this

Comment: If System Preferences > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces is enabled, then windows **can't** span multiple screens. See the [the 10.9 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/#10_9Spaces).

Comment: @zneak I may be completely stupid, but can I do the screen solution via a WindowController, pass that as a parameter along side the nib file name for the window ?

Comment: @LarsNielsen maybe :) I didn't post an answer because I'm not completely sure of the mechanics, but I still thought that I could be somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the user has their desktop Mirrored there is no way to display one NSWindow on all screens.

The only way to do this is to pretty much create a new window for each screen.

If your NSWindowController, NSWindow etc... complies with NSCopying, just copy it and take a look at this post regarding displaying NSWindows in various screens:

[How to change the NSScreen a NSWindow appears on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195977/how-to-change-the-nsscreen-a-nswindow-appears-on)

Hope this helps.